# Center text inside link buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar on a web page that I need to center the content in. Also for some reason it's backward... instead of being Home, Shop, About, and Contact from left to right. It's Contact, About, Shop, then Home.

I need to know A: How to turn it around and
B: How do I center the text inside the buttons?

Here is all my code:

```
<div id="masthead"></div>
<h1>American Backcountry</h1>
</div><!-- end masthead -->
<ul id="mainnav">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.htm">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
#mainnav{

    height:30px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 45px;
    }

#mainnav li{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #6a4622;
    float:right;
    padding-right: 45px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    margin-left: 3px;
    width: 40px;
}

#mainnav a:link{
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    color:#dfd098;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;

}
```

**EDIT** (after answer accepted)

Okay, I was able to center everything and get it to hang out to the right.

Now, I need to change the color of only the Home link and also change the text color... How would I do this? I need to target JUST the home link.

Comment: your float:right cause the reverse order.

Comment: Thanks, I took that out but now it moved to the left... How do I keep it to the right of my page but in order? Also I need to center the text... ?

Comment: Hi Sylvia, questions and answers on Stack Overflow are intended to serve as a reference for all site users, now and in the future. By removing your original question and replacing it with a completely different one, the original answers don't make sense anymore. I hope you don't mind, but I have restored the original question. However, I have also posted your second question at the bottom of the original post as an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a horizontal navigation bar on a web page that I need to center the content in. Also for some reason it's backward... instead of being Home, Shop, About, and Contact from left to right. It's Contact, About, Shop, then Home.

The reason is the `float: right` property in your code. With this property, your elements will be displayed from right to the left, in the exact order they appear in the code, giving you the feeling that they are backwards.

> Would you happen to know how I can make my Home link a different color and text color than the other three?

I recommend you to read more about [`CSS Selectors`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [`Pseudo-classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

```css
#mainnav {
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 45px;
  text-align: right;
}
#mainnav li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #6a4622;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
#mainnav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #dfd098;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
#mainnav li:first-child a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="masthead"></div>
<h1>American Backcountry</h1>
<!-- end masthead -->
<ul id="mainnav">
  <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="shop.htm">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.htm">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wonderful! But now it's in the center of the navbar... how do I scoot it all over to the right of the page?

Comment: i thought you wanted it on the center. there you go, updated it to display the links on the right side

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can make my Home link a different color and text color than the other three?

Comment: what kind of rule you want to use to change the color? there are lots of ways you can achieve that

Comment: The Home link uses a background color of #f4efdd and a text color of #38471d 
 You may not edit the HTML! You do not need to add a class or id to the Home link. Use a CSS selector that selects only the Home link.

Comment: This is what my assignment says about it. I just don't know how to target only the Home link.

Comment: updated the example and the description with some resources, so you can study more about selectors.

Comment: Thank you again so much, I'll read up on them, this is all just a LOT to take in and learn but I'll get there! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

The benefits of flexbox are:

1. minimal code, so it's efficient
2. centering, both vertically and horizontally, are simple and easy
3. it's responsive
4. it represents the future of CSS layouts

**CSS**

```
#mainnav {
    display: flex; /* NEW - establish flex container */
    justify-content: flex-end; /* NEW - right-align flex items (li) */

    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 45px;
    list-style: none;
    }

#mainnav li {
    /* display:inline-block; */
    background-color: #6a4622;
    /* float:right; */
    /* padding-right: 45px; */
    border:1px solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    margin-left: 3px;
    width: 75px; 
    display: flex; /* NEW - establish (nested) flex container */
    justify-content: center; /* center text horizontally, in this case */
    align-items: center; /* center text vertically, in this case */
}

#mainnav a:link{
    /* display: block; */
    height: 100%; /* adjusted */
    color:#dfd098;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /* text-align: center; */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nhp0gsw6/1

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).*